# UNC path move script to pass username & password

Tags: powershell

I am writing a PowerShell script to search files for a specific pattern (example 00857682YK) and move the files to a directory located via UNC path. The problem I am running into is that the UNC path requires a login to write files. The script cannot write the file if said user is not logged into the UNC path. How do I add logic into the script to pass the username/password to the UNC directory?

```
get-childitem "C:\EDI\Comms\AS2\AS2 SPS\IN\" -filter *.* -recurse |  
  select-string -list -pattern "00857682YK" |  
    move -dest \\RAMP\c$\Ramp\Document\Barnana\In
```

Answer (score 0):

To authenticate on a remote computer before copying (or moving) files to it, you can use the `net use` command. Example:

```
net use \\computer1\ipc$ /user:username *
# put your PowerShell command here
net use \\computer1\ipc$ /delete
```

The `*` parameter on the `net use` causes it to prompt interactively for the password for the remote computer.

Answer (score 0):

```
move -dest \RAMP\c$
```

I'm assuming that's supposed to be `\\RAMP\c$`.  This is an administrative share.  Only users that have administrator rights on `RAMP` have access to the administrative shares *regardless of any file system permissions*.  If you're going to be running this script remotely on computers that end users will be logged into, this seems like a staggering bad idea from a security perspective.

If you want to grant remote access to a specific folder, share that folder out and assign the correct file permissions to that folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new PSDrive using Credentials using the New-PSDrive Cmdlet

```
$cred = get-credential
new-psdrive -Name ramp -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\server\share -Credential $cred
```

Then you could use the `ramp:\` drive in your code.